# How to determine which Apache Drill drillbit was selected when connecting via zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-drill, mapr

I'm using a zookeeper connection string to get a connection to a drill cluster.  I would like to log which drillbit (hostname or IP address) I successfully connected to, but I can't find any property or method on the [java.sql.Connection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) to get this information.

I tried `connection.getMetaData.getURL`, but that just returns the zookeeper connection string I used to get the connection (scala code below):

```scala
import java.sql._
Class.forName("com.mapr.drill.jdbc41.Driver")
val con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=<server1>:5181,<server2>:5181/drill/<cluster_name>...")
con.getMetaData().getURL()  // returns "jdbc:drill:zk=<server1>..."
val st  = con.createStatement()
val res = st.executeQuery("select *,'findme' from sys.drillbits")
while(res.next()) { println(res.getString(1)) }
```

If I grep the `drillbit_queries.json` logs on all of the drillbit servers for `findme`, I can find which drillbit was used to execute the query.  For tracking down connection issues, I'd like to be able to log which drillbit is being used from the application, rather than have to grep logfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t forget that you can ask these questions directly to the Apache Drill community on the drill mailing lists or slack channels. See https://drill.apache.org/community-resources/ for more details.

Specific to your question, check out the system tables (https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-system-tables/). The sys.profiles_json table, in particular, seems to be the one that is likely to give you the information you need.

It is a generally pretty safe bet that if you can see the information that you need in the web interface for Drill that you will also be able to find that information in the system tables. Commonly, a quick scan of the docs and some trial queries will give you the info you need. Since the web interface is open source, you can also grovel the source code to figure out how the web interface gives you the pertinent info.

In particular, this query gives roughly what you are asking for:

```
with t1 as (
    select convert_from(x.json, 'JSON') js from sys.profiles_json x
)
select t1.js.queryId id, t1.js.foreman.address foreman, t1.js.query query
from t1
limit 3
```

Comment: Thanks Ted.  I'm hoping to avoid having to make a query to obtain this information.  The web interface for drill has you go directly to a drillbit URL, so I wouldn't expect to find any zookeeper-related code in there.  I did scan the `sqlline` source code, since it logs which drillbit it connects to in `sqlline.log`--`Foreman drillbit is <drillbit host>`--but I couldn't find that string anywhere.  I think that string/log is in the MapR (not the open-source) Drill JDBC driver.

Comment: Also, looking at the most recent "n" profiles wouldn't be reliable for us, since we have multiple applications that are querying Drill, and some are multi-threaded and may issue multiple queries at about the same time.  (I'm really surprised that there doesn't seem to be a way to get the drillbit hostname from the connection object.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found what I was looking for:
https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/client/DrillClient.java#L462

```
private void connect(DrillbitEndpoint endpoint) throws RpcException {
   client.connect(endpoint, properties, getUserCredentials());
   logger.info("Foreman drillbit is {}", endpoint.getAddress());
}
```

So now the question becomes (assuming the MapR Drill JDBC driver is similar), can our application get access to that DrillbitEndpoint object?

In the UserClient code (DillClient is a wrapper around UserClient) I see that
https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/rpc/user/UserClient.java#L109

```
DrillbitEndpoint endpoint;
```

is a private instance variable, and I don't see any public method to expose it.  So I don't think there is a way for our app to get access to that.

Ted suggested using Java reflection or and/or a future pull request for Drill to expose this field.

---

If you don't mind making another query, https://drill.apache.org/docs/troubleshooting/#identify-the-foreman has the answer:

```
SELECT hostname FROM sys.drillbits WHERE `current` = true;
```

That will return the hostname of the drillbit you are connected to (i.e., the foreman) for your session.